# Search any word in two strings query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have this mysql query.

Example of database fields:

```
Family           Repair                                   Cost
iPhone 6         LCD Replacement Original with Camera     $ 10
iPhone 5         Power or Volume Flex original            $ 5
```

I already use CONCAT to unit the strings (Family + Repair). But I have to type EXACTLY the words to return data.

If I type:

```
"iPhone 5 Power or Volume Flex Original"
```

It return correctly

But if I type:

```
"iPhone 5 Flex Volume"
```

It doesnt

Or:

```
"LCD Original iPhone 6"
```

It doesnt too.

SQL QUERY:

```
 $sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(' ', family, repair) as fapair FROM list WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', family, repais) LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' Limit 5";
```

How can I do it? Thx!!

Comment: you will need to separate the search words then use a wild-card search with like.

Comment: you can use `"WHERE repair LIKE %'iPhone 5 Flex Volume%'"`

Comment: You have an SQL vulnerability, never put untrusted user data into a statement without validating it and stripped it

Comment: MATCH AGAINST http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @nogad bad idea